# Error when inserting a datetime into mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table `reports` with a field `report_date`. Type of the field is set to `TIMESTAMP`.

When I try to run the following query:

```
insert into reports (report_date) values (1990-03-25 02:16:36)
```

I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '1990-03-25 02:16:36' for
>   column 'report_date' at row 1 0.000 sec

However the query runs ok with the value `'1999-03-25 02:16:36'`.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**
Here is a screen shot of the INSERT query:
[image: ![enter image description here]
As you can see, I'm quoting the value date, but I'm still getting the error for `"1990-03-25 02:16:36"` but not for `"1991-03-25 02:16:36"`.

I have inserted thousands of records this way. I just have a problem with this date. I have also tried it on Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95c03/1/0) and it works but not on my machine.

Comment: because this is how sql works, you have to use quotes around dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the bug to explain the error, but I avoided it by changing the data type from `TIMESTAMP` TO `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) MySQL's documentation about `datetime`, this is what it says:

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Now, if you use values like `1990-03-25 02:16:36` without quotes, MySQL interpretes `1990-03-25` as an expression and tries to evaluate it, e.g.:

```
SELECT 2016-01-01;
```

The above gets treated as an expression and results in `2014` value (here's [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/766b8/9/0)). But then, it encounters `00:00:01` and can't determine what to do and hence, it fails.

If you enclose the value in quotes, the whole `string` gets treated as a single token and gets parsed into a `Timestamp`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Warrio what's the column type for `mydate`? I have tried the same query and it works fine. SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f3985/1/0).

Comment: column type is set to TIMESTAMP as you can see in this screeen shot https://ibb.co/cDE4fk

Comment: Try it yourself on your machine if you have mySql and you will have the same error.

Comment: @Warrio could you create an SQL Fiddle like I did above and send me the link?

Comment: @Warrio attached script works fine, I am unable to reproduce it.

Comment: Open your own mySql tool and run these queries:
CREATE TABLE yourDB.mytable2 (myDate TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO yourDB.myTable2 (myDate) VALUES ("1999-03-28 02:04:57");
You will get the error. I don't know what Fiddle is using as a database.

Comment: @Warrio I did that already and could not reproduce it. Even the SQL Fiddle attached in question works fine. Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySql mariadb-10.2.3-win32 on Laragon, windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose dates in single quotes like

```
insert into `reports` (`report_date`) values('1990-03-25 02:16:36')
```